# First Input Delay (FID) and Interaction to Next Paint (INP) showing N/A in the google pagespeed for a Website

Tags: seo, google-pagespeed, core-web-vitals

When I use Google PageSpeed to evaluate my website, I receive 100 ratings. Furthermore, essential web vitals also indicate passing.

However, why am I receiving a N/A for First Input Delay and Interaction to Next Paint?

Does my code have a problem, or do I need to adjust certain settings?

PFA Image for output from Page Speed Insights

[image: Core Web Vital Scrren Shot]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78046780/first-input-delay-fid-and-interaction-to-next-paint-inp-showing-n-a-in-the-g